# How to upload photo to Facebook via graph api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, winhttp

i am having a desktop application. My requirement is to upload photo to facebook using graph api. I am able to post message to user wall via application. But i am not able to upload photo. i am getting an error "EXPECTS UPLOAD FILE" . i went through the documentation specified in the link

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/

I am using Winhttp for the connection. So how the file name will be specified? Whether the file name be specified in the URL itself?'

Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the paraemeters message and source as multipart/form-data and send it with winhttpsendrequest